# Matrix in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I am currently having a problem in regards to a matrix table every time i attempt to add in a new field it is drilling down. Is there anyway to prevent this so that information stays on the present table and does not drill down?

Comment: need more details like - sample data, sample presentation you need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are adding the new field in row, column or value. This will reset the matrix and you will need to drill down/up to attain desired view.

In case you are not trying this and worried about other slicers/visual changing your matrix, you can edit interaction in view menu.

Otherwise you wanna try bookmarks to maintain same state of your report page.